# CSS RollOver Image via Background-position-x with Cover/Contain?

Tags: html, css

iPhone devices look best when you give an image that is twice the size of the actual pixels needed.  When you use contain it will make the image look crisp and nice.

I made a background image for a control with 2 states.  On & Off.  To be efficient instead of making two separate images I made a file where all I had to do was change the background-position-x property when I clicked on the control to change the image.

This works, except... that contain will show the entire background image with both 'on & off' states.

Right now I'm using 2 different images to make the control change the image.

Is there a way to 'contain' the image but only to a portion of the source image files pixels? This way I could make it look nice but use 1 file instead of 2?

Or does this even matter for efficiency?

Comment: can you create a fiddle: jsFiddle ?

Comment: Yeah I think I need to to explain this better, let me re-make this question with a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For background image sprites (that's what you call numerous images pieces in one file) I prefer to use elements like  and position and size them so they're the exact size of the sprite piece I want to show.

So let's say you have a  that needs a hover effect or anything that might need to images to swap in and out. The easiest thing to do is to add a  inside the image so your basic html would be:

```
<a href="#><span></span></a>
```

Then you size the  and add position:relative;

Then on your span set the height and width to 100% and add position:absolute; top:0; left:0; and apply your background image to the span.

Then you can do things like a:hover span { background: 0 10px; } etc etc.